# Testing Linux kernel drivers

Tags: testing, command-line, linux-device-driver, entry-point

i am newbie to linux kernel and all, is there any way to check the entry points of  linux kernel drivers from command line? say for leds-lp5523?

i have seen t[his](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/leds/leds-lp5523.txt) document says we can run some sample LED patterns by running the echo commands by running

```
cd /sys/class/leds/lp5523:channel2/device   echo "load" > engine3_mode echo "9d80400004ff05ff437f0000" > engine3_load   echo "111111111" > engine3_leds   echo "run" > engine3_mode
```

But i cant find this /sys/class/leds/lp5523:channel2/device directory in my Ubuntu x86-64 PC.
Can anyone help me on this.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

This file will not be created until you actually have an LP5523 connected. I doubt this is the case on your PC as this is an i2c chip.

Else, you found the correct documentation. You can usually find two different interfaces for drivers, either device files (usually found in /dev) that are using the usually syscalls (open, read, write, ioctl) or a sysfs interface (found in /sys), the documentation is then found in `Documentation/ABI/`.

The best way to find whch interface the driver is using is still to read the source code for that driver.

Comment: Thank you....let me ask you one more doubt...How can i identify the device file opened by lp5523.ko under /dev drirectory?can you explain with an example..sorry if i am asking too much..

Comment: A device file is not opened by a driver. Userspace does that. Then, the major and the minor are used to link that file to the driver and call the appropriate function. However, the LEDs subsystem doesn't use any device files, only the sysfs interface. You may read http://free-electrons.com/doc/training/linux-kernel/linux-kernel-slides.pdf starting with slide 197.